# Передача данных контроллеру

Tags: ajax, javascript

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему этот код не передает контроллеру `$_POST['num']`?

```
        $("#ajaxBtn").click(function(){ 
            //$("#imgLoad").show(); 
            $.ajax({
                url: "<? echo CController::createUrl('section/show'); ?>",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"num": num},
                cache: false,
                success: function(response){
                    if(response == 0){  // listening server answer
                        alert("Больше нет записей");
                        //$("#imgLoad").hide();
                    }else{
                        //$("#content").append(response);
                        num = num + 6;
                        //$("#imgLoad").hide();
                    }

                }

            });
        });
```

upd:

```
<?... 
    if (isset($_POST['num']))  
    {  
        $criteria->limit = $_POST['num'];  
        $sections = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);  
    }  
else echo var_dump('undefined'); ?>
```

undefined показывается, т.е. экшн вызывается.

Comment: Миллион причин.

Comment: отметить Ваш ответ как правильный?

Comment: вызывать ``$(function() {...})`` в ``$(document).ready(function(){...})`` это круто

Comment: ок, спасибо, убрал.
что еще?

Comment: URL лучше указывать явно.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['num'])) {
                    $criteria->limit = $_POST['num'];
                    ;sections = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
                }
                else
                    echo var_dump('undefined');

undefined показывается, т.е. экшн вызывается

Comment: Что возвращает?

    CController::createUrl('section/show');

Comment: в общем, логика у меня такая:  
сначала ищу $criteria->limit = 6;$sections = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);  
по нажатию кнопки опять же вывзываю этот контроллер, но проверяю - если request->isAjaxRequest, то $criteria->limit = $_POST['num']; и опять  
$sections = Post::model()->findAll($criteria);   
и рендерю то же самое представление:  
$this->render('show', array('model' => $model, 'sections' => $sections));

Comment: @SterSwift - посмотрите что вам приходит

     echo file_get_contents('php://input');

Если строка вида 'num=значение_переменной' приходит, тогда клиент не посылает заголовок "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", соответственно проблема в клиентском коде, а именно в настройке функции ajax. Точнее написать не могу т.к. с `$.ajax` практически не работал, че там и как - не помню

Comment: Для отладки в контроллере:

    ob_start();
    print_r($_POST);
    file_put_contents('log', ob_get_flush());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Извините, а переменная num вообще есть?
Попробуйте

> alert(num);

перед

> $.ajax({

Answer (score 1):

поддерживаю насчет явного урл-а, а еще не нравится мне

> data: {"num": num},

предлагаю попробовать строкой:

```
data: "num="+num,
```

Comment: Это не имеет значения.

Comment: попробовал - не помогло
а явный урл - это урл на action.php? а если у меня экшн в контроллере?

Comment: а есть ли возможность извежать экшена? пока это самое узкое место во всей конструкции, имхо..

Answer (score 1):

а фактичести значение num откуда берется?
и на сколько я понимаю вы работаете с yii , но там вроде используют такую комбинацию для указания маршрута 
`<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("RBCountry/JQGetData")?>`

Comment: ммм, не захватил num
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var num = 6;
    $("#ajaxBtn").click(function() { 
...

экшн то вызывается.
$criteria->limit заменил на $criteria->offset.
не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте без кавычек:

```
$("#ajaxBtn").click(function(){ 
       //$("#imgLoad").show(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "<? echo CController::createUrl('section/show'); ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: {num: num},
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                if(response == 0){  // listening server answer
                    alert("Больше нет записей");
                    //$("#imgLoad").hide();
                }else{
                    //$("#content").append(response);
                    num = num + 6;
                    //$("#imgLoad").hide();
                }

            }

        });
    });
```